# text/xml parsing to dataframe

Tags: r, httr, xml2

Using httr package, I pulled content from an api as follows. the content received is "text/xml". The output data from below is pasted at the end.
I converted to xml as follows

```
res_xml <- httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
xml2::read_xml()
```

When I checked the children it seems to have node_set

```
xml_children(res_xml )

{xml_nodeset (4)}
[1] <type value="searchset"/>
[2] <total value="1"/>
[3] <link>\n  <relation value="self"/>\n  <url value= ...
[4] <entry>\n  <link>\n    <relation value="self"/>\n ...
```

But, when I pull the "entry" node, there seems to be no data.

```
xml_find_all(res_xml ,".//entry")
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Instead of working with xml format, I converted to list and that is a complete nested lists of lists with unequal entries.

```
xml_list <- xml2::as_list(res_xml)
```

I would need a data frame for specific entries or more favorably complete xml output as separate tables, so that I can select the data I can work further much easily. Hence, tried the following. But, the output is all NULL.

```
lst <- xml_list$Bundle$entry 
lst %>% dplyr::bind_rows()

# A tibble: 17 x 4
   relation url    Patient          mode  
   <list>   <list> <list>           <list>
 1 <NULL>   <NULL> <list [0]>       <NULL>
 2 <NULL>   <NULL> <named list [1]> <NULL>
 3 <NULL>   <NULL> <named list [1]> <NULL>
 4 <NULL>   <NULL> <named list [1]> <NULL>
 .....
```

when I noticed the str(lst) the list has NULL list() and attr(value). I am interested in the attr value.  If I convert the xml to JSON, everything is NULL.

Any help on how to flatten this list appropriately would be appreciated. or More better I can parse directly using xml2 package.

---

input data

```
<Bundle xmlns="\"http://hl7.org/fhir\""><type value="\"searchset\""/><total value="\"1\""/>
  <resource>
      <Patient><id value="\"TzfXm.YeCZh5GLGCXoCQqmjyn9vSjtJtIlcakCeyfbEcB\""/>
        <extension url="\"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-race\"">
          <valueCodeableConcept>
            <coding><system value="\"urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.5.104\""/><code value="\"UNK\""/><display value="\"Unknown\""/></coding><text value="\"Unknown\""/></valueCodeableConcept>
        </extension>
        <extension url="\"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity\"">
          <valueCodeableConcept>
            <coding><system value="\"urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.5.50\""/><code value="\"UNK\""/><display value="\"Unknown\""/></coding><text value="\"Unknown\""/></valueCodeableConcept>
        </extension>
        <extension url="\"http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-birth-sex\"">
          <valueCodeableConcept>
            <coding><system value="\"http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/AdministrativeGender\""/><code value="\"F\""/><display value="\"Female\""/></coding><text value="\"Female\""/></valueCodeableConcept>
        </extension>
        <identifier><use value="\"usual\""/><system value="\"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.172.3.7.5.737384.0\""/><value value="\"E296\""/></identifier>
        <identifier><use value="\"usual\""/><system value="\"urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.172.2.7.5.737384.100\""/><value value="\"410000236\""/></identifier><active value="\"true\""/>
        <name><use value="\"usual\""/><text value="\"Mother Milltest\""/><family value="\"Milltest\""/><given value="\"Mother\""/></name><gender value="\"female\""/><birthDate value="\"1978-05-06\""/><deceasedBoolean value="\"false\""/></Patient>
    </resource>
    <search><mode value="\"match\""/></search>
  </entry>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: Judging by the example data you've given us, you might be getting `NULL`s because the nodes don't exist. I can't find `entry`, `relation`, or `url` in the example XML. I can find `mode`, but no value is returned because of the odd use of double quotes, e.g. `\"\"match\"\"`. When I replace them with one `\"` I'm able to get the attribute value.

Comment: yeah true the fhir output is bit weird. when I call the same api in python with header information as "Content-Type:application/json". I do get a JSON output which is much cleaner. But, the same call in R resulted in a "text/xml", not sure why.  the <resource> tag has most relevant info, that like to make a df.

Comment: If that same API is able to send more useful responses in JSON format, have you tried sending the same httr request with a `accept_json()` included? 
https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/content_type.html

Comment: `res <- httr::GET(base_url,
  path = path,
  query = search_query,
  headers,
  accept_json()
)
res` This works